# I Install expo-cli@6.0.5 globally, then I try to install 'expo install expo-location' it gives this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, terminal, expo

The term 'expo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

this is my global install

```
+-- axios@0.27.2
+-- **expo-cli@6.0.5**
+-- express-generator@4.16.1
+-- express@4.18.1
+-- nodeman@1.1.2
+-- nodemon@2.0.19
+-- react-native-cli@2.0.1
+-- react-native@0.69.5
`-- touch-cli@0.0.1
```

Comment: All the cli commands are different for expo 6+, take a look at the documentation https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/

Answer (score 1):

Try `npx expo install expo-location`

Answer (score 0):

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    **"location": "expo install expo-location"**
  }
```

npm run location
After adding this I install the expo-location.